# Сложный заголовок в DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf

Необходимо создать сложный многоуровневый заголовок в DataGrid (C# WPF). Есть ли сторонние гриды c такой возможностью?

Answer (score 2):

Над DataGrid делаеш Grid в нем кол-во стобцов делаеш равным DataGrid биндиш ширину колонки Grida к ширине колонки DataGrida

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите в сторону DevExpress, Telerik например...

Не могу прямо-таки посоветовать кого бы то ни было из этих контор, так как ради одного-двух элементов управления тащить за собой придётся довольно много всего, да и в идеале использовать лишь определённые из их компонентов не сильно удобно.

WPF был создан как конструктор, так что приведите пример того, что требуется сделать, возможно и не придётся прибегать к сторонним разработкам.

Answer (score 0):

[WPF DataGrid Custommization using Style and Template](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586132/WPF-DataGrid-Custommization-using-Style-and-Templa)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `DataGrid` из [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid&referringTitle=Home)